# How to open my favorite editor from PsychoPy Builder

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm using PsychoPy Builder. I'd like to write codes with vim. How should I open it from PsychoPy Builder? Sorry about my poor English.

Comment: Please, reformat your question to better explain the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

The "builder" is a gui interface to the psychopy library. If you want to write code then you probably want to use psychopy as a library. To do that you will have to figure out where the library is stored on your system, and that might be easier if you don't use the stand-alone version, but get one of the library version and install that (you could use the tools pip or easy-install) if you have used those python tools before. Then you will find Psychopy whereever your other libraries get stored which will be something like .../python27/site-packages/Psychpy-/psychopy/.... With the first set of ... depending on Mac/Linux/FreeBSD/Windows

Navigate down that path through demos; coder; stimuli; unti you see a .py file. Then you can open that up in Vim and modify it as practice.

If none of this makes any sense, then you probably want to use the builder and standalone until you get some more hands on experience. Cheers,